# Ansible provisioning over jump server with different private keys

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have got a server (`S`) which is only reachable from a jump server (`J`). My public key is already copied to `J` and there is a different set of public/private key which is copied to `S` to allow authentication from `J` to `S`. The key pair on my local machine is different then the one on `J`.

Now I want run my ansible script to provision `S` going over `J`. I tried the ProxyCommand option in `group_vars`of my inventory file, but it ends up asking me for the user password on `S`, however authentication on `S` is supposed to be done automatically through PK.
Following is how my inventory file looks like:

```
[application-server]
192.168.174.29
```

And my group_vars look like this:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q jump-server"'
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: The edit was not only replacement, it also removed the ambiguity and corrected the wrong facts added initially. The problem is clear and obvious in the current description that Ansible is unable to provision my environment with the above mentioned configuration. Infrastructure is explained in words as well as drawn in the diagram.

Comment: I have updated the question again to eliminate my theory. I would appreciate if you could point to the solution now.

Comment: @techraf you are wrong. The `ProxyCommand` will issue IO redirect and authorize you to the target server directly from local machine. Environments that require authentication keys on some shared machines do not sound very safe. Using `ProxyCommand`, there is no way around it (force the `ssh` to authenticate you from the jump server).

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje for your constructive response (finally!). _"Environments that require authentication keys on some shared machines do not sound very safe."_ Can you please elaborate this a bit more why does it not sound very safe?

Comment: The private keys should be private. If it is hanging on some shared server, evil `root` can read and misuse that keys. On the other hand, if you have them on your computer, they can be either encrypted (and available from `ssh-agent`) or even stored on the HSM (which is even more secure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProxyCommand` will issue IO redirect and authorize you to the target server directly from local machine. This is much safer than having private keys hanging in some shared server. Using `ProxyCommand`, there is no way around it (force the ssh to authenticate you from the jump server).

What you should do is to copy the keys from the jumpbox back to your machine (or use the same one as you use for jump server).

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje. Finally I got Ansible to work by using the **-A** option in my _ProxyCommand_. 
On the other hand, if I try to ssh from the terminal, it still asks me for the password. Strange!

Comment: My ProxyCommand now looks like this:
`ProxyCommand ssh -A -W %h:%p jump-server`
This works in Ansible, but if the following doesn't work from my shell:
`ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A -W %h:%p jump-server" 192.168.272.29`

Comment: Where do you have the private key B and how is it named? The first jump does not work or the second?

Comment: Private key B is named as `id_rsa` and it resides on jump server (`J`). Public key for B is copied to the `authorized_keys` file of Target server `S` to allow passwordless authentication from `J`to `S`.

Comment: As I already said two times, copy the private key to the local host and it will be working for you from terminal as expected.

Comment: `ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A -W %h:%p jump-server" 192.168.272.29`
This command asks me for password on `abc@192.168.272.29` (`S`)

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion of copying private key to localhost, my only confusion is that how is it working with Ansible with the current setup (i.e. different private keys on localhost and on jump server).

Comment: I understand that copying private key from jump server to localhost should fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have so deep understanding of Ansible to answer this question.

Comment: So I finally found that `ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A -W %h:%p jump-server" 192.168.272.29` works fine only if the private key on jump-server (`J`) is added to the ssh-agent.